# Apache: ExpiresDefault doesn't work, whereas "Header" does. How comes?

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

If I do this:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|mp3|mp4|css|js|php)$">
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 30 days"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

It doesn't set properly the Expire header, whereas if I "force" it by hand like this:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|mp3|mp4|css|js|php)$">
    ExpiresActive On
    Header set Expires "Thu, 18 Jan 2012 20:00:00 GMT"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

It works. This implies 2 things:

- mod_expire is installed (`IfModule mod_expires.c` is true)
- the Expire header is **not** modified after this rule is applied.

What am I missing?

By the way: if you have any solution to make it work I'm your man!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I've got it from the official documentation [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_expires.html):

> Note that if you use a modification date based setting, the Expires
>   header will not be added to content that does not come from a file on
>   disk. This is due to the fact that there is no modification time for
>   such content.

So it works only for static files, and not for all the other ones: they're not static.

Answer (score 0):

This one got me stumped as well because AFAIK, it should work so I tried it on a test VM varying the N days and refreshing.  Works fine for me.  My Apache version is

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Nov 18 2010 21:17:19
```

Any the headers for a test file (using chrome developer tools) (with N=15) show:

```
Date:Mon, 09 Jan 2012 01:48:43 GMT
ETag:"7574-5-4b60e88a820a1"
Expires:Tue, 24 Jan 2012 01:48:43 GMT
```

My thought is that any `ExpiresDefault` can be overridden by a `Header set Expires`.  Have you grepped the `.htaccess` hierarchy to make sure that your `ExpiresDefault` isn't being overridden at a lower level.

If you don't want htaccess files doing this you need to disable them in your http config.

Comment: I have no htaccess file (high performance rules), everything is in vhost, and there's no directives like this in vhosts. They are global. And they are applied to the vhost, because, as I emphasized in my question, the 2nd example works, and it changes the Expires.

Comment: @Olivier, sorry I missed your emphasise on vhost, but my point still stands have you explicitly disabled .htaccess files just in case one exists in your application directory/directories, because any {ExpiresDefault} here will override yours. Ditto have you grepped the Apache config hierarchy to ensure that some other {ExpiresDefault} isn't overriding yours as per the [Configuration sections precedence] (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/sections.html).  AFAIK, this isn't an Apache bug, so the next most probable explanation which fits the evidence that you've provided is a precedence issue.

Comment: Or as you point out they are dynamic.  Sorry -- I took it as given that they were static because you were using `ExpiresDefault`.  If they are dynamic then your generating script should actively control caching and issue the correct headers (e.g. Date, Expires) also process If-Modified-Since and Etag request headers and issue a 304 response if not updated